# Using ClassifierCompositeItemWriter and FlatFileItemWriter to write to multiple files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to create a spring batch job that will read from MySQL database and write the data to different files depending on a value from the database. I am getting an error :

```
org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to
at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.write(FlatFileItemWriter.java:255)
```

Here's my ClassifierCompositeItemWriter

```
ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<WithdrawalTransaction> classifierCompositeItemWriter = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<WithdrawalTransaction>();

    classifierCompositeItemWriter.setClassifier(new Classifier<WithdrawalTransaction, 
            ItemWriter<? super WithdrawalTransaction>>() {          
        @Override
        public ItemWriter<? super WithdrawalTransaction> classify(WithdrawalTransaction wt) {
            ItemWriter<? super WithdrawalTransaction> itemWriter = null;
            if(wt.getPaymentMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("PDDTS")) { // condition
                itemWriter = pddtsWriter();                 
            } else {
                itemWriter = swiftWriter();
            }
            return itemWriter;
        }
    });
```

As you can see, I only used two file writers for now.

```
@Bean("pddtsWriter")
private FlatFileItemWriter<WithdrawalTransaction> pddtsWriter()
```

And

```
@Bean("swiftWriter")
private FlatFileItemWriter<WithdrawalTransaction> swiftWriter()
```

I also added them as stream

```
@Bean
public Step processWithdrawalTransactions() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("processWithdrawalTransactions")
            .<WithdrawalTransaction, WithdrawalTransaction> chunk(10)
            .processor(withdrawProcessor())
            .reader(withdrawReader) 
            .writer(withdrawWriter)
            .stream(swiftWriter)
            .stream(pddtsWriter)
            .listener(headerWriter())
            .build();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` creation done within a `@Bean` method?

Comment: Hi @MichaelMinella, yes 
Bean("withdrawWriter")
    StepScope
    ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<WithdrawalTransaction> withdrawalWriter() {

}

Comment: Try to make the return type of the two beans ItemWriter instead of FlatFileItemWriter.